# If statement to display error if data is not present in a file

Tags: bash

```
echo "Please Enter a Forename";
read Forename;

if [ ! $Forename ]; then
    echo "$Forename not found";
else
    grep -n "Forename: $Forename" $Filename | sort;
```

fi

I am trying to use the above code to check if a string the user enters is present in a file, the file name is `AddressBook.txt` which I have assigned to the variable `Filename`.

Can anyone advise me whether this would work or could you suggest a better way to check the file.

Comment: you can use `grep -q "some-string" "$Filename"`

Comment: yeah it just seems to display a blank screen to me

Comment: `if [ ! $Forename ]` doesn't work as you want to at all...

Comment: the screen just displays nothing not even the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print the contents of a file using cat for instance:

```
contents=$( cat $filename )
```

Now you can check if the string `contents` is empty:

```
if [ -n "$contents" ]; then
  echo "The contents of the file are empty"
fi
```

You can use `grep` to check for a particular string:

```
contents=$( grep "$pattern" "$filename" )
```

And from here on the if will be the same.

Comment: Thank you contents=$( grep "$pattern" "$filename" ) was exactly what i needed